# How to retrieve file's with grid fs

Tags: python, django, image, mongodb, gridfs

I have inserted image file with gridfs in mongodb with python and I want to retrieve that file with another function. How can I retrieve the file. I am using djanog and python(2.7).Thanks in advance!

```
def file_grid(request):
   datafile = open('jobs.jpg',"r");
   thedata = datafile.read()
   fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
   stored = fs.put(thedata, filename="testimage")
   return HttpResponse("inserted")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
gridout = fs.get_last_version("testimage")
```

The `gridout` object is an instance of [GridOut](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridOut) for reading files. You could get all the bytes at once with `gridout.read()`, or iterate over chunks of bytes like:

```
for chunk in gridout:
    do_something_with(chunk)
```

GridFS chunks are about 256k by default.